# Trying to give text a gradient effect in Illustrator cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, gradient

I'm trying to change the "3" to a gradient, but when I click the gradient icon it just goes black and the gradient settings to not take effect. I tried going to `object > expand` but that didn't do anything.

Here are screenshots.

### **Selecting the fill works.**

[image]

### **Selecting the gradient does not work.**

[image: Gradient just turns it black]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a new fill to the text via the **Appearance Panel**. Apply the gradient there. And **be certain to move the new fill so it is *above* the "Characters" item in the panel.**

[image: Appearance]

Live text can not contain a gradient fill as the primary fill (don't ask me why).

Comment: Still no luck :( [Here's a screenshot of my update.](http://i.imgur.com/lNx6J4Z.png?1?3379)

Comment: Move the gradient fill **above** the <characters> in the Appearance Panel. Note the *order* of things in my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Mike is right. Just open your file, ensure you are on the right layer. (if you can't see Appearance on your right panel, goto window on the menu-bar and chose Appearance from the drop-down list)

Select your text, click on the little arrow next to the four lines on your right hand-side in Appearance. From the list select Add new fill, click the arrow next to the colour on fill and chose your fill.

Same thing for stroke.

Answer (score -2):

Just 'Add New Fill' to the text from the options in the Appearance panel then gradients will work on live text.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Gg3wlfosBY

Comment: Please explain better. Suppose the link you gave is broken then your answer is useless ... BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!